# Filter json entry with null child

Tags: php, json

I have following json

```
{
"id": 81,
"bank_id": 2,
"service_id": 1,
"created_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:23",
"updated_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:23",
"alias": "remit",
"alias_burmese": "remit",
"reputation": null,
"contact": null,
"service": null
},
{
"id": 82,
"bank_id": 2,
"service_id": 2,
"created_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:24",
"updated_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:24",
"alias": "international remit",
"alias_burmese": "international remit",
"reputation": {
"id": 1,
"bank_service_id": 82,
"reputation_points": "-2",
"created_at": "2014-12-25 10:08:40",
"updated_at": "2014-12-25 10:08:40"
},
"contact": null,
"service": {
  "id": 2,
  "parent_id": 1,
  "service": "International Remittance",
  "service_burmese": "International Remittance",
  "is_active": "1",
  "created_at": "2014-09-12 08:31:57",
  "updated_at": "2014-09-12 08:31:57",
  "service_order": 1
}
}
```

I want to ignore the entry will NULL service .. so that my entry will be like below

```
{
    "id": 82,
    "bank_id": 2,
    "service_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:24",
    "updated_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:24",
    "alias": "international remit",
    "alias_burmese": "international remit",
    "reputation": {
    "id": 1,
    "bank_service_id": 82,
    "reputation_points": "-2",
    "created_at": "2014-12-25 10:08:40",
    "updated_at": "2014-12-25 10:08:40"
    },
    "contact": null,
    "service": {
      "id": 2,
      "parent_id": 1,
      "service": "International Remittance",
      "service_burmese": "International Remittance",
      "is_active": "1",
      "created_at": "2014-09-12 08:31:57",
      "updated_at": "2014-09-12 08:31:57",
      "service_order": 1
    }
    }
```

What could be the best option.. i was trying to convert json to array and try to filter using array_filter??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter), [json_decode](http://php.net/json-decode) and [json_encode](http://php.net/json-encode) to achieve this. Please note that your JSON sample is not valid until you wrap it with array notation `[]`.

```
<?php
// callback function for array_filter
function filterNullService($obj) {
  if(!is_null($obj->service)){
    return $obj;
  }
}

$json = '[{
  "id": 81,
  "bank_id": 2,
  "service_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:23",
  "updated_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:23",
  "alias": "remit",
  "alias_burmese": "remit",
  "reputation": null,
  "contact": null,
  "service": null
},
{
  "id": 82,
  "bank_id": 2,
  "service_id": 2,
  "created_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:24",
  "updated_at": "2014-12-05 06:40:24",
  "alias": "international remit",
  "alias_burmese": "international remit",
  "reputation": {
    "id": 1,
    "bank_service_id": 82,
    "reputation_points": "-2",
    "created_at": "2014-12-25 10:08:40",
    "updated_at": "2014-12-25 10:08:40"
  },
  "contact": null,
  "service": {
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "service": "International Remittance",
    "service_burmese": "International Remittance",
    "is_active": "1",
    "created_at": "2014-09-12 08:31:57",
    "updated_at": "2014-09-12 08:31:57",
    "service_order": 1
  }
}]';
$array = json_decode($json);

$result = array_filter($array, "filterNullService");
$jsonResult = json_encode($result);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
print_r($jsonResult);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function with second param as `true` to convert JSON string to array. Then filter array with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and encode array to JSON with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

If you need example code, let me know.